# SAS. calculate % from DISTINCT COUNT

Tags: sas

I am working in SAS Studio Version: 2022.09.

I am working with survey data and will be tracking Region-Facility that has not submitted a survey in over 3 weeks. Surveys are voluntary but ideally facilities will submit a new survey weekly.

| Region | Facility (Type&Name) | Date Survey Submitted |
| --- | --- | --- |
| North | Hospital-Baptist Hospital | 1/01/2023 |
| South | PCP-Family Care | 1/01/2023 |
| North | PCP- Primary Medical | 1/08/2023 |
| South | PCP-Family Care | 1/08/2023 |
| North | Hospital-Baptist Hospital | 1/15/2023 |
| North | Hospital-St Mary Hospital | 1/15/2023 |
| West | Daycare-Early Learning | 1/15/2023 |
| West | Hospital-Methodist | 1/15/2023 |
| South | Daycare-Early Learning | 1/15/2023 |

To obtain a list of facilities by region that submitted before but have not submitted in 3 weeks. Since we do not expect to be successful with every facility, we will stop following facilities after 10 weeks.

```
Data have;
    set want;
    DaysDiff=intck('day', Date, today());
run;

proc sort data=have;
    by Facility Region Date;
run;

data have;
    set have;
    by Facility;
    if last.Facility;
run;

proc sort data=have
   out=SurveysMissing;
   BY Region Facility;
   WHERE DaysDiff>21 AND DaysDiff<70;
run;
```

To assist in determining significance of losing facilities that had not submitted recently, I would like to obtain a %.

[Total # of facilities per REGION that have not submitted survey >21 <70] / [Total # of facilities per REGION that have reported in the last 10 weeks]

```
/*#facilities not submitted >21 AND <70 /*

proc sql;
SELECT Count(Distinct Facility) AS Count, Region
FROM have
WHERE DaysDiff>21 AND DaysDiff <70
GROUP BY Region;
run;
```

```
/*Count of Distinct Facilities per Region*/
proc sql;
SELECT Count(Distinct Facility) AS Count, Region
FROM have
WHERE DaysDiff <70
GROUP BY Region;
run;
```

Would I need to create tables and do a left join to calculate %?

Thanks.

Comment: Is reporting as of beginning of the week? You can use the today() function and then go back 10 weeks, but need to align the dates correctly so what defines a 'week' in terms of the date you include in your data.

Comment: If you can include a more complete set of sample data that could then be used that would also be helpful.

Comment: Sample data edited. The "facility" is actually a combination of 2 fields (Facility Type & Facility Name) in hopes of having a unique identifier as there could be multiple facilities with the same name, in different areas of the state. The surveys ideally should be submitted on Sunday (with weeks prior data), but respondents have the ability to choose any date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Proc SQL a true condition resolves to `1` and false to `0`.  You can leverage this feature to compute the ratio of sums of expressions or binary flags.

Example:

Compute the ratio based on a subquery that flags facilities

```
proc sql;
  create table want as
  select
    region, sum (isquiet_flag) / sum (submitted_flag) label = 'Fraction of quiet facilities'
  from 
    ( select region, facility
      , min(today() - date_submitted ) > 21 as isquiet_flag
      , min(today() - date_submitted ) < 70 as submitted_flag
      from have
      where today() - date_submitted < 70
      group by region, facility
    )
  group by 
    region
  ;
```

Answer (score 1):

In your last data step for `have`, add an indicator for missing survery.

```
data have;
set have;
by Facility;
if last. Facility;
surverymissing = (daysdiff > 21); * contains 1 if condition is true, otherwise 0;
run;
```

Then use `proc summary` to compute your numerator and denominator for each region. The numerator is the sum of `surveymissing` while the denominator is the count of the same.

```
proc summary data=have nway;
where daysdiff < 70;
class region;
var surveymissing;
output out=region_summary (drop=_:) sum=SurveysMissing n=TotalFacilities;
run;
```